# RewriteRule in .htaccess for assets folder from absolute path to relative path

Tags: regex, angular, linux, apache, .htaccess

Iam trying to redirect all the `<img src="./../../../assets/images/*.png">`
to `<img src="./assets/images/*.png">`

How can i achieve the same using htaccess

The absolute url path can vary from `./../ to ./../../..` so on

Anything that is been called as absolute path should be rewritten to relative path ie, should remove `./../../` using htaccess

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: Neither `./../` nor `./../../..` is an absolute path...

Comment: am also having the same issue, can somebody good in htaccess can help ?